# R vegan simper analysis: modify distance matrix

Tags: r, distance, euclidean-distance, vegan

I am using a simper analysis from the Vegan package in order to determine which amino acid are responsible for the variation in protein composition between different samples. As I understood from this [discussion](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.ecology/month=20120401), The simper() function uses Bray-Curtis. I would need to use another dissimilarity index, typically euclidean. How could I modify it within the function? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing only the dissimilarity is trivial, but the dissimilarity you use should be such that you add and analyse terms by species. Terms of *squared* Euclidean distance are such. However, `simper()` makes all kind of strange tricks with dissimilarities, and I am not at all sure these tricks are valid for squared Euclidean distance (I am not even sure that they are valid for Bray-Curtis that we used, but at least they accord with the published method). NB, we *do warn* against the use of `simper`. This is an extract from the help page -- I hope you have already read this:

> The results of ‘simper’ can be very difficult to interpret. The
>        method very badly confounds the mean between group differences and
>        within group variation, and seems to single out variable species
>        instead of distinctive species (Warton et al. 2012). Even if you
>        make groups that are copies of each other, the method will single
>        out species with high contribution, but these are not
>        contributions to non-existing between-group differences but to
>        within-group variation in species abundance.

That said, here are the lines you should change to switch from Bray-Curtis to squared Euclidean. However, I suggest you don't use this function:

```
diff --git a/R/simper.R b/R/simper.R
index 35fa189..f60c57f 100644
--- a/R/simper.R
+++ b/R/simper.R
@@ -13,9 +13,8 @@
         n.b <- nrow(gb)
         for(j in seq_len(n.b)) {
             for(k in seq_len(n.a)) {
-                mdp <- abs(ga[k, , drop = FALSE] - gb[j, , drop = FALSE])
-                mep <- ga[k, , drop = FALSE] + gb[j, , drop = FALSE]
-                contrp[(j-1)*n.a+k, ] <- mdp / sum(mep)
+                mdp <- (ga[k,, drop=FALSE] - gb[j,, drop = FALSE])^2
+                contrp[(j-1)*n.a+k, ] <- mdp
             }
         }
         colMeans(contrp)
@@ -53,9 +52,8 @@
         contr <- matrix(ncol = P, nrow = n.a * n.b)
         for (j in seq_len(n.b)) {
             for (k in seq_len(n.a)) {
-                md <- abs(group.a[k, , drop = FALSE] - group.b[j, , drop = FALSE])
-                me <- group.a[k, , drop = FALSE] + group.b[j, , drop = FALSE]
-                contr[(j-1)*n.a+k, ] <- md / sum(me)
+                md <- (group.a[k,,drop=FALSE] - group.b[j,,drop=FALSE])^2
+                contr[(j-1)*n.a+k, ] <- md
             }
         }
         average <- colMeans(contr)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jari. Indeed I read about limitations related to using SIMPER analysis. In my case I use simper() as a post-hoc test for adonis permanova to estimate the contribution of each amino acid to the variation in protein composition between samples. So far I did not find a good alternative to the simper other than performing a simple ANOVA for each amino acid. But this does not answer the same question. You may have other suggestions?